# Changing the src of an image with an unknown id with jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#likeHeart').on('click', function() {
        var clickedSoundId = $(this).attr( "soundId" );
        console.log(clickedSoundId);
        $.get("http://localhost:8000/like/"+clickedSoundId+"/", function(data, status){
            console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $(this).attr("src","http://localhost:8080/Icons/favorite.png" + '?' + Math.random());
            $(this).attr("srcset","http://localhost:8080/Icons/favorite.png" + '?' + Math.random());
            console.log($(this).attr('src'));
            console.log(data["count"]);
            $("#likeCount"+clickedSoundId).text(data["count"]);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is the multiple image with the same id but different soundId

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/Icons/like.png" srcset="http://localhost:8080/Icons/like.png" id="likeHeart" soundId="{{ s.id }}" height="15" width="15"><p id="likeCount{{s.id}}">{{s.nbLike}}</p><br>

var clickedSoundId = $(this).attr( "soundId" );
```

Give me the good id.

But

```
$(this).attr("src","http://localhost:8080/Icons/favorite.png" + '?' + Math.random());
```

Doesn't change the image visually, but when i do a  :

```
        console.log($(this).attr('src'));
```

The src is changed correctly ...

here is the fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/bussiere/7fh5n9kd/

Regards and thanks

Comment: It should work. Can you provide a `fiddle`. I believe you are on the wrong context.

Comment: @LingasamySakthivel done thanks

Comment: If you solved the problem, post as an answer. It may be helpful to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, don't use same IDs for different elements. It's not valid HTML markup. Use class or other attribute.

Let's return to your question. Try this format: **data-soundId="{{ s.id }}"**

You can get this attribute with **.data** selector like this: **$(this).data( "soundid" );**

And don't use uppercase for **.data**.

**Example:**

```js
$('.clickable').click(function(){
  var soundid = $(this).data('soundid');
  alert(soundid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable" data-soundid="15">15</div>
<div class="clickable" data-soundid="20">20</div>
<div class="clickable" data-soundid="25">25</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can not select multiple targets with **ID**.
each id should not be more than one.
try giving the images same class rather than ID